# Export datagridview content to excel

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, export-to-excel

I am tring to export datagridview content to excel but it throws exception.
I have a method

```
private void exportDataGridToExcel(DataGridView grd)
        {
            if (saveFileToExcel.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application Excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

                Workbook wb;
                Worksheet ws;

                wb = Excel.Workbooks.Add();
                ws = (Worksheet)wb.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

                for (int i = 0; i < grd.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
                {
                    ws.Cells[1, i] = grd.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
                }
                for (int i = 0; i <= grd.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j <= grd.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        ws.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = grd.Rows[i - 1].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                    }
                }
                wb.SaveAs(saveFileToExcel.FileName, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal);

                wb.Close(ws);
                Excel.Quit();
            }
        }
```

and when i click on button it calls that method like this

```
private void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
     exportDataGridToExcel(dataDaily);
        }
```

but it throws exception in this line of code `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application Excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();` this exception:

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))."

Comment: I think the exception message doesn't tell much about the error, but taking a look at your code, seems there are few mistakes,
grd.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText
[i - 1]?? while your index starts from 0; similarly grd.Rows[i - 1]

Comment: I deleted - 1 and i throws another exception 
 An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll


Additional information: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

When this line of code is called
 ws.Cells[1, i] = grd.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;

Comment: the general concept of arrays is that they are zero-indexed; having said that grd.Columns[i - 1]?! (i - 1) means index of -1, there is no index of minus value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Make sure you a referencing the correct interop dll for the version of excel you have installed on your computer.

In your references, you will see a version for excel. You need to make sure you have that version of excel installed on the machine loading the DLL.

Comment: But wouldn't it show error in code if reference is wrong?

Comment: No it wouldn't because it is a COM class and the dll itself is loaded at run time

Comment: What a noob I am :( so can you please tell me how to check if reference is ok?

Comment: There is a version number when you add the reference. You can also right click the reference and check for the version there.

Comment: I found it, and it says Microsoft Excel 2013 :D and I have 2007 :D hahahah thank you very much friend :D